# Duplicate Same Legend Twice in Ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am preparing a chart where I have client's requirement to put same legend on top and bottom. Using ggplot I can put it either at top or at bottom. But I am not aware about option of duplicating at both the places.

I have tried putting legend.position as c('top','bottom') but that is giving me error and I know if should give error.

Can it be done with other libraries? I want to same legend twice at top and at bottom?

Take this code for an instance

```
library(ggplot2)
bp <- ggplot(data=PlantGrowth, aes(x=group, y=weight, fill=group)) + geom_boxplot()
bp <- bp + theme(legend.position="bottom")
bp
```

Comment: You can create a separate ggplot legend and ggplot figure and you can combine and arrange them into a composite figure.  Please provide a reproducible example if you need details.

Comment: @Djork - Done. Take this example and add legend on top as well.

Answer (score 1):

You have to work with the intermediate graphic objects (grobs) that ggplot2 uses when being plotted.

I grabbed a function that was flowing around here on StackOverflow to extract the legend, and put it into a package that is now on CRAN.

Here's a solution:

```
library(lemon)
bp <- bp + theme(legend.position='bottom')
g <- ggplotGrob(bp)
l <- g_legend(g)
grid.arrange(g, top=l)
```

`g_legend` accepts both the grob-version (that cannot be manipulated with ggplot2 objects) and the ordinary ggplot2 objects. Using `ggplotGrob` is a one-way street; once converted you cannot convert it back to ggplot2. But, as in the example, we keep the original ggplot2 object. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the use case, a center-aligned top legend may not be appropriate as in the contributed answer by @MrGrumble here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46725487/5982900

Alternatively, you can copy the `"guide-box"` element of the ggplotGrob, append it to your grob object, and reset the coordinates to the top of the ggplot.

```
createTopLegend <- function(ggplot, heightFromTop = 1) {
    g <- ggplotGrob(ggplot)
    nGrobs <- (length(g$grobs))
    legendGrob <- which(g$layout$name == "guide-box")
    g$grobs[[nGrobs+ 1]] <- g$grobs[[legendGrob]]
    g$layout[nGrobs+ 1,] <- g$layout[legendGrob,]
    rightLeft <- unname(unlist(g$layout[legendGrob, c(2,4)]))
    g$layout[nGrobs+ 1, 1:4] <- c(heightFromTop, rightLeft[1], heightFromTop, rightLeft[2])
    g
}
```

Load the `gridExtra` package. From your ggplot object `bp`, use `createTopLegend` to duplicate another legend, then use `grid.draw` to produce your final figure. Note you may need to alter your plot margins depending on your figure.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
bp <- ggplot(data=PlantGrowth, aes(x=group, y=weight, fill=group)) + geom_boxplot()
bp <- bp + theme(legend.position="bottom",  plot.margin = unit(c(2,0,0,0), "lines"))
g <- createTopLegend(bp)
grid.draw(g)
# dev.off()
```

This will ensure the legend is aligned in the same way horizontally as it appears in your original ggplot.